# Tricky Audits in Review Queue

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have been reviewing for enough time to get acquainted with "*how reviewing works*"; but I found some exceptional cases.

In following case, my decision was "Recommend Deletion" (as it should be a comment on other post). The system, however, says that this should not be deleted:

---

> [image: Picture of audit]

---

It strongly appeared to me that this answer should have been a comment; so, I reviewed it accordingly and I failed the audit and got a review ban.

There was an another question titled "***how to show all apps together in play store with single name ?***" which, as we know, can be solved with `package name` (not the exact solution but still close to solution). So, I marked this question "*Looks OK*", which resulted in failing that audit claiming that the question is not related to the SO site.

Referring to the attached image, what can I do if I found a bad review audit?

Comment: You're doing it right now: posting about it on Meta to draw attention to it, and possibly have it removed from your audit history.

Comment: This is why I open most questions and answers I review in a new tab...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah i try that too , there was no accepted answer and the other answer had little deep explanation too so unluckily i went with this decision

Comment: @PavneetSingh That you feel *an answer* isn't well explained doesn't make it not an answer.  It is potentially grounds for downvoting the answer, if you feel it isn't useful, but how well it explains *its answer* doesn't change that it is an answer.

Comment: @Servy that is again some thing opinion based and seems like it's not possible for me to bend the things more for you so the option is you can answer this question (if you please )

Comment: @PavneetSingh No, it's not *an opinion* that answers shouldn't be deleted just because they're poorly explained.  It's site policy.  Whether or not you think that is a *good* policy is a matter of opinion; you're certainly welcome to not like the site's policy on when a post should be deleted, but it's a *fact* that the site's policy is that an answer should not be deleted just because you don't think it is sufficiently well explained, and that you need to abide by those policies when using the review queue.

Comment: @Servy let me put your previous comment in this way , we should not have "low quality flag" because if a answer is poorly explained doesn't mean pavneet you should flag it as "low quality answer"  , cool man then there will be far less reviews to cover and i an not going against SO policy , LQF and other flags are provided by site to use it plus i am sure since from the beginning of SO many new features and rules introduced , modified  time-to-time e.g flags

Comment: @PavneetSingh There is no "low quality answer" flag.  There is a "very low quality" flag for posts that are *literally nonsensical*; cases where a cat walked across the keyboard or someone posts just complete gibberish.  The flag is not for posts that are very clearly answers to the question that you just feel are wrong, incomplete, short, or otherwise of low quality.  That's what voting is for.  Using VLQ to flag answers that you think are wrong, or too short, is abuse of those flag.  Deleting *actual answers* based on those flags is also wrong.  This audit is correctly informing you of that.

Comment: @Servy you sure  yeah that was just a hint low quality flags or  answers and again you said the same opinion based thing by saying "Deleting actual answers based on those flag" , some flag it , some flags are false , some flags are true

Comment: @PavneetSingh No, it's not a matter of opinion.  You can't just delete whatever you feel like.  Whether or not you feel a post is worth upvoting or downvoting is a matter of opinion.  It is not based on fact; if you want to downvote a post, you can.  But deletion is different.  You don't just get to delete answers because it's your opinion that they should be deleted.  Posts are deleted when they meet criteria for deletion, and to do otherwise is to *violate the site's rules*, as you found out when you failed the audit.

Comment: @Servy first i am not the one who will delete it and i didn't said it i want to or i have any issue so don't impose this thing again & again plus about breaking the So policy too (i am here for an answer ) and  as it's again some review based system or something and you don't think it should be deleted or taken away as test audit , ok,  me and other reader read it or future reader can read this in you initial comments , so no point in flooding the comments section with same statements

Comment: @PavneetSingh But you *did* try to delete it.  You *would* be responsible for deleting it.  You wouldn't be the only one; you'd be one of six, but that doesn't absolve you.

Comment: @Servy again MR.Servy your opinion , ok it's matter a lot , thanks for your suggestion and you want to keep the ban going on me but still my opinion (maybe few others ) don't see in that way

Comment: @PavneetSingh It's appreciated you're trying to understand why you failed that audit. I'll note the answers you've received are correct as to that reason. Currently though - given the information now and historically I see no reason to lift the ban - it will expire automatically in 6 days. Feel free to use that time to digest the information and suggestions you've been given.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for your suggestion ,i have bought some herbals to digest it, will take it soon :P but seems like this is way more trickier than a test , just to check user is paying attention or not , seems like the option to me that ,i will be using "skip" more on these test-case

Comment: @Servy is right. An answer which makes any attempt, no matter how naive, drunken, or incompetent, to answer the question [is an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and should not be deleted. This does not mean that these answers are good quality - if you see an answer that depends on strings being mutable in Java, downvote it into oblivion so that it is tucked away from mortal men for all time - but don't delete it.

Comment: @RobertColumbia i appreciate it , but if you read the accepted answer in the link you provided says the same what i thought  `When an answer says:

You probably want a FileOutputStream [LINK]
I don't think that is an answer. It still needs to make clear HOW the FileOutputStream could be applied in the solution.` and thanks for the link

Comment: @PavneetSingh `i will be using "skip" more on these test-case` Good! [There is no shame in using "Skip"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/2747593).

Comment: @ScottWeldon yeah dude  i totally agree using it as a last resort  :)

Comment: Flags and reviews should not be used as substitutes for delete votes. You should only flag content that cannot be handled through downvotes and delete votes, and must be addressed by a moderator. The fact that some flags will be handled in the queue does not mean that you should expect that your flag will be handled by community review. As a reviewer, you should be handling the flags as a moderator would, otherwise you're just adding to the confusion. If it should not have been flagged, the flag should not be validated via review.

Answer (score 10):

This is why we don't want those questions, because it generates that kind of answers. The correct path here is to click the "link", vote to close the question (it may need other kind of votes too), and skip. Problematic questions tend to have problematic answers.

Comment: yeah it should be done on this A,B and other low quality questions although i expect some solution from SO about my ban and to remove these tricky test , 7 day ban feel like somebody freeze me (my review privilege ) on a super sunny day

Comment: @PavneetSingh you can downvote the answer, it automatically makes it ineligible for audits, for the other, maybe a flag can be more expedite.

Comment: @Yakk actually, I would vote to delete it if I could, so no, I wouldn't stress that. My point comes across perfectly fine, problem questions generate problems answers, deal with the source of the problem as it's more effective.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  If you [examine the original question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039303/when-explicitly-initializing-stdoptionals-should-i-use-nullopt) both the question and the answer are reasonable, and deserve neither downvotes nor deletion.   Noticing why Braiam's answer to this meta question is wrong is tricky without reading the original reviewed question and answer in full context.

Comment: @Yakk but is this the baseline we want for subsequent answers? I doubt so. As the saying goes, *in Rome, do as roman do*, users tend to follow examples, if the examples don't exist, then they are less likely to answer other questions where better answers can be provided in the same fashion.

Comment: @Braiam What?  Yes, we want that question and answer on stack overflow.  It asks something that isn't trivial to work out unless you are already proficient in it.  The answer is correct, and useful.  It is not great, but better than 90% of the questions and answers on this site.  You don't delete something because a better answer or question could possibly exist; if that is your standard, what are the odds any of your (or my) answers or questions would pass *that* bar.

Comment: @Yakk very high, and that's the point. If it was easy then we wouldn't be here trying to find something interesting to answer.

Answer (score 6):

You rightfully failed the audit because you voted to delete a correct and useful answer.

The question asked for any reasons why A or B should be preferred, where on the technical side, there is no difference between A or B. An answer that points this out and explains that the only reasons to prefer one over the other are non-technical ones is exactly the sort of answer that question is looking for, and wholly appropriate for the site.

Note that even if the answer weren't correct, that still wouldn't be a reason to delete it. Wrong answers are still answers; it would only be a reason to down-vote it. The criterion is whether it *attempts* to answer the question.

Comment: maybe your right in your opinion , but most members must have seen these kinds of low quality or not an answer reviews in review queue everyday ( i too ) plus if you show this to 10 guys then i guess mostly find this as "not an answer" and my experience about answering is , member don't accepts or like wrong answers and it's kind of confusing "Wrong answers are still answers" means it still wrong plus i have no issue with answer, though makes no sense putting it as a test in audits (7 day ban )and worse thing is i can't even do anything about it

Comment: @PavneetSingh If it were a wrong answer, it would've almost surely received downvotes, and the downvotes would've meant it would not have been used as an audit. But it's not a wrong answer, it's correct and useful, so why should it *not* be used as an audit?

Comment: that is something a controversy , what you said is not obvious every time , even many time,  there are enough proofs (if required then i can post the links too) plus even there was a question posted on meta(received 60 + votes ) oppose to your previous comment but it's other things i don't wanna bring in.

Comment: @PavneetSingh No, this isn't controversial.  This is *unquestionably* an answer.  You *unquestionably* performed the wrong action by trying to delete it.  That the audit managed to catch a user trying to delete a post that is very clearly an answer means *it was doing its job*.

Comment: Which moves us to the next point, we don't want those kind of answers, so we should deal with the questions that ask for them instead.

Comment: @Servy i have already presented my views in the best way i could and about the down-vote on this question  , it's proves my point i.e voting in some cases are opinion based and it's a judgement of the voter and i have no right to question about it , although you can post your opinion as an answer so that other can do some sort of discussion on your opinion

Comment: there are only two answers on question included this one and still no answer is  accepted

Comment: @PavneetSingh You didn't present any view at all.  You said that the answer should be deleted and nothing else.  You gave no reasoning for why it should be deleted.  It's an answer to the quesiton.  You saying that it should be deleted, with no supporting evidence, doesn't mean that it should be deleted.  It meets none of the criteria for deletion.  This isn't an opinion.  (Whether you agree with the site's rules for deletion *is* an opinion, but that it violates none isn't an opinion.)

Comment: @Servy if a 10/-8 answer on a 15/-1 question isn't controversial, I don't know what would be...

Comment: @PavneetSingh How is whether or not an answer is accepted relevant?

Comment: @Braiam Nobody has yet to provide even a single reason for why the post should be deleted.  The post is an answer, by all of the site's criteria.  Nobody has said anything that would contradict it.  That people don't *like* the fact that this is how the system works is a (potentially controversial) opinion that they can hold, but that the post is an answer isn't really a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Servy that it is an answer doesn't mean that deserves to be on the site, but I reckon is more productive to deal with the question that asks for those kind of answers.

Comment: @PavneetSingh Consider that some users who ask questions just never or only rarely accept answers. Does that mean that all the answers given to those users' questions should be deleted? Of course not. Using that as a reason is just being ridiculous.

Comment: @Servy i would been agreed with you that accepted answer doesn't matter but the OP of this question has 10K+ repo  (not a newbie )and seems like OP didn't see this as an answer

Comment: @Braiam If you would like to propose a change in what the criteria for deletion are, you're more than welcome to do so.  As it is, the question in no way meets any of the site's criteria for deletion, so until that changes, voting to delete such an answer from the review queue is wrong, and will be enforced accordingly.

Comment: @Braiam Questions asking whether there are solid technical differences to prefer A or B should be fine, questions whether there are stylistic reasons to prefer A or B should be closed. I see the question we're talking about as more of the former than the latter.

Comment: @PavneetSingh That they didn't accept the answer doesn't mean that the post isn't an answer, it means that the author didn't acknowledge it as the best complete answer to their question.  There are *millions* of answers on this site that aren't accepted, but that are still answers.

Comment: My, isn't this a long discussion for a comments section? ;)

Comment: @hvd and Sevy you can check the ration of unaccepted answers , 70 of time you find OP repo around 500 (except if he didn't asked any popular question :P) though there is still sense what you said about accepted answer (30% is even huge) but this is not the question is about

Comment: @PavneetSingh Okay, I checked. For the user in question, out of the 392 asked questions that have received answers, the user has accepted 191 answers, just a little under 50%.

Comment: "Useful"? You mean you think this is good answer quality!?!

Comment: @cat Yes, I do. The exact same words may form a very poor answer to some questions, but in this specific case, the "It does not matter at all" provides exactly what was asked in the question. It could have been phrased as "They do exactly the same thing" instead to make the meaning clearer without context. Do you agree that that would be useful?

Comment: **IF** that is useful for this particular case, then no doubt the question itself is flawed in a fundamental level and should have been closed, not answered.

Comment: @hvd I'd agree with correct; it may have answered the OP's question.  Useful is less obvious, as it (weakly) implies it is *useful to stack overflow*.  Stating "correct and useful" as your only description of the low quality answer to a low quality question is, in essence, misleading.  (Note it isn't "very low quality", just low quality).

Comment: @Yakk The only explanation given for why the answer is low quality seems to be that it is an answer to a low quality question, and I disagree that the question is low quality. Sometimes good questions have simple answers. To me, this was one of those times.

Comment: @hvd ah, I tracked it down.  Yes, that is an acceptable question and an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

So, in this **specific case**, here is the Q&A:

[When explicitly initializing std::optional's, should I use nullopt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039303/when-explicitly-initializing-stdoptionals-should-i-use-nullopt)

The question is an acceptable one.  It asks if there is any difference between two options, and if so which should be used.

The correct answer is "they are identical".

A vote to delete of a correct answer of an acceptable question is a bad thing.  You failed your review audit.  It is correct you failed your review audit.  You should not be deleting acceptable answers to acceptable questions.

There are rules about when you should delete/close questions and answers.  At the margin, it is a matter of opinion.  This answer is nowhere near any of the marginal cases for deleting an answer.

---

The initial evidence you provided does make it look poor.  Even if it was a poor answer to a crappy question, deleting the answer would be wrong.  A delete is not a super-downvote.

It is not a comment, it answers the question.  Failing to provide evidence does not justify deleting an answer.  At worst, it justifies downvoting.

A poor answer is often prompted by a poor question.  Tracking down the question and seeing if it deserves downvoting and closing is a good option.  If you lack sufficient expertise in the subject at hand, you should not be voting or voting to close or delete at this point either.

In fact, there are 5 people who thought this particular question deserved closing.  I happen to disagree; I have voted to reopen.

Regardless, even if the question was horrible, the problem is the question not the answers.  VTC question is questionable; vote to delete answer is not.

Comment: i get your opinion and most part is almost similar with the already given answer by hvd , so you can read the initial comments on that question (if you please ) plus how would you justify the difference between a poor answer and a comment and isn't it confusing that one side of you answer saying it's a crappy question and other side you voted to reopen it ? although SO guys always promote quality .  A little concern , i didn't wanted to reveal related guys , don't know this link suppose to be here or not

Comment: @pavneet Suppose the question was "what is an apple" instead of "what is an answer".  A picture of an apple with an arrow is not an apple (link only).  A pile of twigs is not an apple (vlq).  A sign saying "apples wanted" or "do you have apples?" or "What kind of apple?" Is not an apple (comment).  An orange is not an apple.  A plastic apple with an ad on it is not an apple (spam).  A half-eaten wisend tiny apple is an apple, just not a great one.  A pile of rotting apple flesh encrusted with flies is not an apple (vlq).  A crabapple is an apple (bad question).

Comment: first very lovely comment , liked it :), although it's still a little matter of opinion , i appreciate yours and i also represented mine though i was just looking for a way to take it away as test because the quality of this post and question not seems upto the test case